# Adding JSF dependencies to Spring Boot prevents reading static resources from the file system

Tags: spring-boot, jsf

This is my project structure (MWE):

```
.
├── build.gradle
└── src
    ├── main
    │   └── java
    │       └── af
    │           └── aps
    │               ├── Application.java
    │               └── config
    │                   └── MVCConfig.java
    └── public
        └── index.html
```

build.gradle

```
ext.appVersion = '0.0.1'

buildscript {
    ext.springBootVersion = '2.0.4.RELEASE'
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'
apply plugin: 'war'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web') // mvc

    // compile group: 'com.sun.faces', name: 'jsf-api', version: '2.2.18'
    // compile group: 'com.sun.faces', name: 'jsf-impl', version: '2.2.18'
}
```

Application.java

```
package app;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
        return builder.sources(Application.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

MVCConfig.java

```
package app.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;

@Configuration
public class MVCConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/**")
                .addResourceLocations("file:/home/hamid/workspace/java/app/src/public/")
                .setCachePeriod(0);
    }
}
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Home page</title>
</head>
<body>The home page</body>
</html>
```

I'm trying to serve the static resources from the file system. It does work. I can see the home page and when I change it and refresh the browser, I see the changes but when I add the JSF libraries to my project, I get a 404 error that the static resources cannot be found. I've googled all I can and searched the docs but I can't figure out what is wrong.

Comment: JSF by default does not handle .html files. And you know springmvc and jsf are 'competing' and totally different frameworks

Comment: I guess you're right. I just checked and I can still load `html` files from my file system (instead of the tomcat directory). I just wanted to know if I could load `xhtml` files the same way. It's irritating to have to compile the project every time because I've made changes to (otherwise static) `xhtml` pages.

Comment: for jsf run in development mode and 'caching' is turned of

Answer (score 0):

The folder `src/public` isn't in the classpath, so it's contents cant be served by spring-boot.

Just move `src/public` to `src/main/resources/public` and everything should work fine.